# Ranking according to value across two variables - r

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
   df<-data.frame(
      var1 = c(rep(c(rep(1,2), rep(2,3), rep(3,2), rep(4,1)),2), 1),
      var2 = c(rep(1,8), rep(2,8),3)
    )


df

    var1 var2
#1     1    1
#2     1    1
#3     2    1
#4     2    1
#5     2    1
#6     3    1
#7     3    1
#8     4    1
#9     1    2
#10    1    2
#11    2    2
#12    2    2
#13    2    2
#14    3    2
#15    3    2
#16    4    2
#17    1    3
```

I would like to make a third variable that is a rank.   Rows get the highest rank if 1) they have the lowest numbers in `var2` - and then according to how low the numbers are in `var1`.   e.g. Rows 1 and 2 with var2=1 and var1=1  should be ranked 1.  Whereas, rows 9 and 10 with var2=2 and var1=1 would be ranked 5.

If my data are arranged in ascending order of var2 and then var1, I did the following using my favorite R function `rle` to achieve the ranking I'm after:

```
rle(df$var1)
N <- length(rle(df$var1)$lengths)
df$ranks  <- rep(1:N, rle(df$var1)$lengths)

df

    var1 var2 ranks
#1     1    1     1
#2     1    1     1
#3     2    1     2
#4     2    1     2
#5     2    1     2
#6     3    1     3
#7     3    1     3
#8     4    1     4
#9     1    2     5
#10    1    2     5
#11    2    2     6
#12    2    2     6
#13    2    2     6
#14    3    2     7
#15    3    2     7
#16    4    2     8
#17    1    3     9
```

This works, but it requires my `df` to be pre-sorted.   I'd like a solution that does not need this.  I feel like this should be a simple one-liner using `rank` and that I'm having a blind-spot.  Any help appreciated - thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
- adding a larger example for testing of suggested answer

```
dput(df1)
df1 <- structure(list(var1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
12L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), var2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), ranks = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 22L, 25L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 26L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 47L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 46L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
29L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 53L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 74L, 74L, 
74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 
66L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 
73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 
82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L)), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "ranks"), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = "data.frame")
```

The ranks variable was got from this suggested answer:

```
df1$ranks1 <- dense_rank(paste(df1$var2, df1$var1))
```

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; dense_rank(paste(df$var2, df$var1))` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Isn't that going to rank into lexicographic rather than numerical order? I think `with(df, dense_rank(dense_rank(var2)+dense_rank(var1)/length(var1)))` works, but there must be a neater way to combine `var1` and `var2`

Comment: @user20637 It is going to follow ASCII collating sequence (as far as I know), try `sapply(paste0(df$var2, df$var1), function(x) sum(strtoi(charToRaw(x), 16L)))`. Eitherway, if you want a numeric order, you can just add `as.numeric` as in `dense_rank(as.numeric(paste0(df$var2, df$var1)))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg No. It's the `paste` (or `paste0`) which converts to character and forces lexicographic ordering. Try `as.numeric(paste0(1.2, 3.1))`.

Comment: See `?Comparison` for lexicographic sorting order - it's not trivial.

Comment: @user20637 in which cases my suggestion won't work?

Comment: @DavidArenburg   - I've added a larger example from some data I was working on.   It returns a df with var1 and var2 as integers.   When using the suggestion of David it does return some odd answers.

Comment: Are `var1` and `var2` always integers? If so `dense_rank(as.numeric(paste0(df1$var2, df1$var1)))` should work. Tough I'm starting to think that just sorting (using some data.table` function such as `setorder`) and then ranking would be the best way to do this

Comment: @DavidArenburg - yes, in the data I'm working with they would always be integers

Comment: So `dense_rank(as.numeric(paste0(df1$var2, df1$var1)))` works for you?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - no, this isn't working for me.   e.g. For the second example I gave above, it appears to rank 1-9 for var1,var2,var3, then 10 onwards for var1,var2,var3, etc.  I'm wondering if this is an idiosyncrasy of the particular example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions involving `paste[0]` will only work if values within each vector are integer with a fixed number of digits. This is because `paste` converts to character and:

1. character (lexicographic) ordering differs from numeric: `rank(c(1 , 2, 11)); rank(as.character(c(1 , 2, 11)))`
2. concatenation introduces ambiguities: `paste0(2,12); paste0(21,2)`

Peter Dalgaard made a relevant post in 2011 http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Function-rank-for-data-frames-or-multiple-vectors-td3765685.html

For now ignore identical rows. Note that rank(x) == order(order(x)) and `order` accepts multiple ordering columns so if you don't mind how identical rows are split `order(order(df$var2, df$var1))` does the job.

This splits identical rows according to their original ordering. There are a number of ways of ranking identical rows http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Strategies_for_assigning_rankings.

In 2011 Peter Dalgaard suggested `ave(order(order(df$var2, df$var1)), df$var2, df$var1)` which gives what Wikipedia calls 'Fractional ranking' and in `base::rank` is the default `ties.method="average"`.

Your example is what Wikipedia calls 'Dense ranking' which isn't available in `base::rank` but - as commented by David Arenburg - is provided by `dplyr::dense_rank`, so you can `library(dyplr)` and use:
`dense_rank(ave(order(order(df$var2, df$var1)), df$var2, df$var1))`

Looking at the code for dense_rank it is just

```
function (x) 
{
    r <- rank(x)
    match(r, sort(unique(r)))
}
```

suggesting that if you don't want to load dplyr and are happy with a 2-statement solution creating another variable - e.g. `r` - you could use

`r <- ave(order(order(df$var2, df$var1)), df$var2, df$var1); match(r, sort(unique(r)))`

Edited to add ...

You can make things a little neater by realising that a data frame is really a list so to rank by columns in order of occurrence:

```
dense_rank(ave(order(do.call(order, df)), df))
```

You are ranking by columns in reverse order of occurrence so

```
dense_rank(ave(order(do.call(order, rev(df))), df))
```

or explicitly specifying columns and their order

```
dense_rank(ave(order(do.call(order, df[,2:1])), df[,2:1]))
```

Comment: The last solution `dense_rank(ave(order(do.call(order, df[,2:1])), df[,2:1]))` works very well.  Very useful to see how you deconstructed this - thanks.